# JUCE - play audio input back

Tags: audio, juce

I am learning JUCE and I am writing a program that just reads the input from the audio card and plays it back. Obviously this is just for learning purposes. I am using the audio application template. This is the code inside the `getNextAudioBlock()` function:

```
void getNextAudioBlock (const AudioSourceChannelInfo& bufferToFill) override
    {

    if(true) // this is going to be replaced by checking the value of a button
    {          
        const int channel = 0;

        if(true) // this is going to be replaced too
        {
            const float* inBuffer = bufferToFill.buffer->getReadPointer(channel, bufferToFill.startSample);
            float* outBuffer = bufferToFill.buffer->getWritePointer(channel, bufferToFill.startSample);
            for(int sample = 0; sample < bufferToFill.numSamples; ++sample)
                outBuffer[sample] = inBuffer[sample];
        }
        else
        {
            bufferToFill.buffer->clear(0, bufferToFill.startSample, bufferToFill.numSamples);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        bufferToFill.buffer->clear(0, bufferToFill.startSample, bufferToFill.numSamples);
    }


}
```

The code is really simple: the content from the input buffer is copied directly to the output buffer. However, I am not hearing anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not showing any code that receives input from the sound card -- if you're not putting it in the buffer someplace else, the buffer you've been given is empty, so I wouldn't expect any output (or perhaps just noise...)

Comment: Please check If you have started the AudioDeviceManager. Audio loop should be active to get the getNextAudioBlock method calling.
One easy way to find if your audio loop is active keep breakpoints in getNextAudioBlock method.